# Ruby: Trying to get two classes to interact with each other

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, object

I'm scratching my head a little bit on how to solve this problem I was presented:

I need to make two classes, Horse and Hay. Horse has initialize methods (colour/type). The Hay class has a method (size) for the hay's stack.

The Horse class must have a give method that takes hay and adds it to an array hay_stack for the Horse. The Horse can take a maximum of 3 Hay eaten and if he does it will print a "Too full!" message.

Finally, the Horse class needs a Eat method where when called will remove one of the Hays from the hay_stack.

Questions:

1. I'm confused on how to model this by using 2 classes. How does the Horse class interact with the Hay class's object? We need to pass information between the two.
2. If we do use 2 classes where should hay_stack be and how do we write the proper info to it?

I've done lots of googling to find my answer but to no avail. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 2 classes, Horse and Hay.

The Horse class will have an array hay_stack of object Hay.

The give method will simply add a Hay object to the Horse's hay_stack with the maximum check ofcourse.

The eat method will remove a Hay object from the Horse's hay_stack.